# R readRDS file through shortcut

Tags: r, file, import, shortcut

I've created a shortcut on Windows which points to a RDS file. Is there a way to 'read' the shortcut and load the file?

I've tried the following command, but failed.

```
readRDS("...")  # with correct location
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `R.Utils` package and it's `readWindowsShortcut` function -> [CRAN link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html)

This is a two-step procedure, where:

1. Using the `readWindowsShortcut()` one converts a `.lnk` file into a list
2. With `readRDS` one extracts the `relativePath` element from the list

Here is a working example with a step-by-step explanation:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4),
                   b = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

# Save to disk (in working directory)
saveRDS(data, file = "data.Rds")

##
# Create a windows link `.lnk` manally
##

# Load (install if necessary) library
library(R.utils)

# Read content of .lnk and store it to an object
path <- readWindowsShortcut("data.Rds - Shortcut.lnk")

# See what's inside `path` object
summary(path)
Length Class  Mode     
header           12     -none- list     
fileLocationInfo  4     -none- list     
relativePath      1     -none- character
workingDirectory  1     -none- character
relativePathname  1     -none- character
pathname          1     -none- character

# Read RDS from `relativePath`
readRDS(path$relativePath)

  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
```